# Is it possible to disable the LaunchScreen.storyboard Fade-Out Animation? (w/ Xamarin Forms)

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms to make a cross-platform application with a splash screen. My splash screen design is simply a centered image with a single color background so that both iOS and Android devices launching my app can seamlessly transition into my Xamarin Forms Shared Code. Once my Xamarin Forms application starts, I land the user on a ContentPage that matches the SplashScreen's layout. From this page, I run all of my app's start-up tasks.

After some modifications on Android, I was able to disable the fade animation between the launcher and the application. Now, I would like to do the same thing on iOS.

Similar to Android, iOS's LaunchScreen.stroyboard has a Fade-Out Animation when transitioning to the main application by default. I would like to know how I can disable the  animation so that I can have my desired SplashScreen transition.

I tried using the Swift Editor Assistant but every time I open it with my LaunchScreen.storyboard, it says "No Assistant Results." Next, I tried to open my LaunchScreen.storyboard with the source code editor. With this I was able to see the code however, I'm not sure what value I need to add or where to add it in order to disable the animation.

Here is my LaunchScreen.storyboard Source Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21507" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="olI-5Z-Ti1">
    <device id="retina6_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="21505"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="k5D-YV-QzF">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="olI-5Z-Ti1" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="g5H-NR-ohv"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="Aaz-be-cI5"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="Ju3-CL-BWr">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="428" height="926"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" image="app_logo_white.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gCl-fY-0VN">
                                <rect key="frame" x="139" y="388" width="150" height="150"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.8901960784313725" green="0.043137254901960784" blue="0.043137254901960784" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="3wl-m6-tKk" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-414" y="215"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="app_logo_white.png" width="245.75999450683594" height="245.75999450683594"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Comment: Make your app's opening screen look identical to the launch screen. Behold, no transition.

Comment: They are already identical. The problem is that there is a fade-out animation when the LaunchScreen.storyboard transitions to my app's opening screen. Android had a similar default effect but I was able to disable it. Now it is a completely unnoticeable  transition on Android. I want to know if it is possible to disable the Fade-Out transition between the LaunchScreen.storyboard and the app's opening screen so that I can have the same result on iOS. @matt

Comment: Our app has an opening screen identical to the launch screen. You can't tell the difference. There is no fade from one to the other. If you see a fade out then you're doing something else wrong. In general the effect should be that your real interface fades in, not out. You haven't given enough info to reproduce this mysterious fade out.

Comment: Create a new Xamarin Forms Project and run it on iOS. There is a default fade out animation as the LaunchScreen.storyboard transitions into the Xamarin Forms App. Since I initially posted this question, I was able to find a solution.  For anybody that is new to making Splash Screens using Xamarin Forms, I'm making a more detailed post explaining everything I did to get my desired splash screen! Thanks for your responsiveness! @matt

Comment: Hey it's cool that you solved it. You can give your solution as an answer to your own question here (totally encouraged on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Haha! Well, unfortunately, the solution I thought I had found didn't actually work so it looks like I'm back to square 1 @matt :(

Comment: This might help: [How do I hide the launch image without fading it out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029536/how-do-i-hide-the-launch-image-without-fading-it-out)

Answer (score 0):

The only workable solution is to recreate the launch screen, using an image view or a child view controller, that is on top of the root view that the app launches to. Therefore, when the actual launch screen fades out, it will fade out to a duplicate view which will render the transition unnoticeable. Then simply remove the duplicate launch screen without a fade animation, or with another animation of your choosing. The only caveat here is to delay the removal of the duplicate view by `0.5` as this appears to be the duration of the fade-out. If you don't implement this delay, you will still see the fade-out animation.

To those who say that if you see the fade-out animation, you must be doing something wrong is incorrect. The fade-out is there and cannot be disabled. The reason these people cannot see it is because their launch screens blend perfectly into the splash view. However, if they changed their launch screens to anything else then they would see it.

Comment: If the application is a cross-platform Xamarin Forms Shell project, how would I connect the child view controller to the Xamarin Forms Shell launch process? By default the LaunchScreen.StoryBoard transitions directly to the AppShell.

Comment: @BrysonScales if the duplicated launch screen is an image, for example, then it would simply be added to the top-most page of the AppShell, the page that the app launches to. If the duplicated launch screen is a view-controller, for example, then it could be its own page in the shell, like any other page, that is the top-most page. From how you describe your app, I think the duplicate launch screen should be an image, or a child view, that is simply an object within the top-most page of the shell (the page that the app launches to). This page would then be responsible for removing it.